# How to validate shipping address per product by city and restrict user

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, shipping-address, billing-address

I am using Magento 1.9 .
I want to create product and make available in only specific cities. And also I want to restrict users on checkout when they select product to ship in the city where the product is not available.

What I have in mind so far is, it will be good to create an attribute named 'city', make it multiselect and add cities as it's options. So now I can create product and assign multiple cities to it. and can be seen at the 'Additional Information tab' on frontend product's page.

But now I want to restrict user if he select orders product available in "New York" and he submitted shipping address with any other city. This should restrict the further process and display message.
My attribute for cites:[image: My attribute city with options]
My attribute above with options.
And on product's backend page: [image: Attribute on product's page backend]

In short, I want to restrict user on checkout and display message. "The product is not available in the specified address/city/location etc"

Comment: Are you using any shipping restriction extensions from the magento connect or is it just default magento?

Comment: Nope, I am not using any such extensions. It is default magento

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just implement an observer, listen on `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` check whether one of the products doesn't match the condition and if it is the case, you can `Mage::throwException`, which throws a Mage_Core_Exception. This exception is catched here:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php:594
```

Then the user gets the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But can you tell me the steps,  how to acheive this ? According to my case.

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is? If you want me to solve your problem, just send me an email, I'm for hire.